# Can I self-sign user-mode USB drivers, or do I need to go through Microsoft's Hardware Program?

Tags: windows, code-signing, signtool

Microsoft has deprecated their support for cross-signed root certificates for kernel-mode drivers: https://knowledge.digicert.com/alerts/Kernel-Mode.html

I occasionally release software with USB drivers (as a pair of `.inf` and `.cat` files).
Until now, I have been signing them with signtool, using:

```
signtool.exe sign /a /ac $ROOT_CA_CERTIFICATE /tr $TIMESTAMP_SERVICE_URL /td SHA256 $MY_CAT_FILE
```

and verifying by:

```
signtool.exe verify /v /kp $MY_SIGNED_CAT_FILE
```

Under the recent deprecation, this no longer works (details below).
The apparent alternative seems to be treating my driver as though it were kernel-mode, and going through Microsoft's full qualification route -- which is cumbersome and prohibitive in several ways.

**Is there an easier way to self-sign my driver, given that it does not require kernel-mode?**

(I am not well-versed in signtool and code-signing, so don't hesitate to tell me if I'm missing something obvious!)

---

Details on the signature/verification failures I'm receiving:

- If I continue to sign using `/ac $ROOT_CA_CERTIFICATE` , I get the following error, which seems due to the expiration of the cross-certificate:
  `Signtool Error: The provided cross certificate would not be present in the certificate chain.`
- If I leave that out, I can successfully sign, but verification with `/kp` fails:
  `SignTool Error: Signing Cert does not chain to a Microsoft Root Cert.`
  Whereas with the `/kp` argument, I get this failure:
  `SignTool Error: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can sign your user-mode driver despite the microsoft change.

If the verification fail, it could be that the signature used a code-signing certificate and, as **SignTool use by default the Windows Driver Verification Policy**, you want instead to avoid it and use the `Default Authentication Verification Policy` to verify your file.

So, on your `verify` command add in the `/pa` option to tell it to use the `Default Authentication Verification Policy` **instead of** the `Windows Driver Verification Policy`, meaning it will look at your certificate stores instead of the limited set of CAs Microsoft trusts with drivers.

```
signtool.exe verify /v /pa $MY_SIGNED_CAT_FILE
```

Should give you a success, eg:

```
Successfully verified: .\Sources\Driver\usbcom.cat
Number of files successfully Verified: 1
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 0
```

Comment: Thank you!
But, a clarification -- will users be able to run my driver, if the Windows Verification Policy fails verification?

Comment: Yes, because it's not a **kernel-mode** driver but an **user-mode** driver.  
If you were signing a kernel-mode drivers then you will have to sign your driver with an EV certificate registered on [the Windows Hardware Dev Center dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/get-started-with-the-hardware-dashboard).